# What is the current "state of the art" in future audio sample prediction, given recent developments in "image inpainting" using deep learning?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, audio, estimation, machine-learning

In the last few years, there have been many breakthroughs in the image processing world regarding repairing "damaged" images, images with corrupt pixels, or even reversing artefacts from formats such as JPEG, which have received media attention. I am trying to determine if these methodologies can similarly be used to predict future samples of audio, rather than pixels of an image.

Some examples:

- https://www.engadget.com/2018-04-24-nvidia-ai-fixes-photos.html
- https://www.dpreview.com/news/3422748291/this-neural-network-can-fix-damaged-photos-and-enhance-low-res-shots
- https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/guide-to-image-inpainting-using-machine-learning-to-edit-and-correct-defects-in-photos-3c1b0e13bbd0

much of which derives from an NVIDIA thesis published in EECV 2018: [Image Inpainting for Irregular Holes Using
Partial Convolutions, EECV 2018](https://eccv2018.org/openaccess/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Guilin_Liu_Image_Inpainting_for_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf).

In theory, this basic method should have a direct analog to audio: where, rather than predicting missing pixels, we're trying to predict the next ms or so of future audio from the last second. So, it can really be thought of as a type of nonlinear prediction, which clearly performs very well.

**QUESTION: What is the state of the art in using this method for audio processing rather than image processing? Is there any published literature on this? Does anyone have any references?**

Below are some examples of the technique that I am talking about in the image processing realm. In all these situations, the missing pixel data is reconstructed from the remaining pixels, which is basically 2D sample prediction; I am hoping to get some insight into the 1D analog of this.

[image: Repairing damaged images]
[image: Reversing artefacts]
[image: Comparison between ground truth and prediction]
[image]

Comment: uff, I basically always write the same to questions that ask "what is the current state of the art": You'll have to read *all the papers* in the field, and then have to ask all researchers, including these that don't regularly publish. That doesn't sound like a feasible thing to ask for – I think you didn't even *mean* to ask that. You meant to ask for a solution for a class of problems you'd like to solve! Maybe instead of adding a lot of images that are unrelated to the problem you're trying to solve, maybe actually describe that class of problems in more detail and ask how to solve them :)

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for your insight. You are right, the problem is that I want to learn to do sample prediction using this particular method, but for audio rather than images. I have also added another picture. Thank you!

Comment: more images really don't make your question better. You haven't described the class of audio problems you want to solve. You wrote a (in my perception, slightly over-visualized) introduction to a different problem, and forgot to describe the problem you want to set out to solve.

Comment: I think I understand. I want to learn to do sample prediction using this particular method or any closely related method, but for audio rather than images. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: I have *some* basic knowledge in audio precoders, and in general time-signal autoencoding, but it's not clear to me which problem you're actually trying to solve, so I'm not sure what to apply that knowledge to. Pictures with white paint over them doesn't easily translate to a 1D signal description for me. That's why I keep on asking you to describe the problem you're asking.

Comment: In all these situations, the missing pixel data is reconstructed from the remaining pixels, which is basically 2D sample prediction; I am hoping to get some insight into the 1D analog of this.

Comment: again, this tells me very little about the specific problem you're solving. Like, does your audio system *know* which one of the sound samples are wrong (*erasure channel*), or does it not know that (some other form of noisy channel)? How long (in time and samples) is the disturbance? As the disturbance compact, or isolated samples throughout? What's the goal of reconstruction? What is the nature of the audio material? I'm going to bed,but I'd like to encourage you to really think about one  (in numbers:1) use case and start with that. Otherwise your question will just become incredibly broad.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia This paper will give you a hook into some of the machine learning literature in that area: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.07704

Comment: Do you wish to minimize the total of the error between each original and the corresponding predicted sample value, or to generate audio that sounds convincing or in the least not disturbing? If future original samples are not input to the generator, then this is audio *outpainting* or *extrapolation*. In packet audio with enough buffering at the audio sink, [packet loss concealment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss_concealment) might be best done by inpainting. Outpainting is simpler to study, as the pattern of missing samples is always the same ...000000000111111111...

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I think the first, but could you elaborate on the difference? And yeah, it's mostly extrapolation that I'm asking about. I'm mostly thinking of this in a situation where you have a realtime audio source, and you want to be able to get N future samples, so you are always estimating them at each time step. Things like LPC are extremely primitive ways to do this, relative to the image processing techniques above, so that is what I was asking about.

Comment: Consider that the original audio samples are random and from identical and independent zero-mean distributions, so white noise. In the first approach, predicting that there is only silence minimizes the square of the prediction error at each sample. As an example of the second, you would generate noise that sounds the same, so that the listener could not tell that the audio was generated rather than the original audio continuing.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I think the former was originally what I was looking for, but the second could also be interesting. I would guess that these inpainting methods are mostly the second type (e.g. match various statistical properties)?

Comment: Definitely they are of the second type, as they do not impose that the distributions of the samples are independent. Unless you are interested in lossless compression, I think the second type is what you should ask about. Some inpainting methods of the second type sample from an approximate joint distribution of the samples in the training data, conditioned on the surrounding image data. But you probably shouldn't limit your question to just those methods by specifying that, unless it is vital to, say, avoid exacerbating racial biases in the generated data.

Answer (score 2):

These Images are FAKE !!!

There is absolutely no way, no algorithm, no nothing that exist that can tell you whether the eyes of a girl are blue or black by just looking at her lips !!!

You can guess, something, good or bad, based on your prior training and the probabilities based on that, but that's just a guess.

The fact that the synthesized images look so **natural** is the key to deceive people into thinking that the algorithm correctly predicts the impossible to fix missing information.

No algorithms can tell whether she had a tattoo in her screwed part of the image !!!

What the algorithm is doing is that you feed it with correct information in many many other training images, from different angles, different illuminations etc. Then the algorithm will try at best (and may succeed just as painting artist would do) to replace the missing pixels from those of the available set... And if she had a tattoo in the mean time; forget about it !

Same is for audio...

Comment: "These Images are FAKE !!!" - alrighty then.

Comment: Anyway, these images are examples from published literature, which is explicitly linked to, of a deep learning-based image inpainting algorithm, which I am looking for audio analogues of.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia  YES If you **present** them as if they are correcting some missing information by an algorithm, then they are simply fake... It's as fake as finding x from x+y = 5 ;-)) as fake as storing 100 bits into a 64-bit register (without arithmetic coding). I didn't mean that they are not what they are, but their presentation is fake! They are producing natural looking images that's all.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia If it's possible to **predict** missing information (hence future), then DO PREDICT my next comment using you AI deep learning resources ;-)))

Comment: I'm predicting that I'm going to drop this comment thread, because what I'm looking for is literature references for nonlinear sample prediction using deep learning.

Comment: i am also quite skeptical.  but if you have some cited references for these reconstructed photos, i would be interested in seeing such.

Comment: The models don't recover ground truth, they just fill in the gaps with something plausible (cf. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg0F5JjKmhA)

Answer (score 2):

i am also quite skeptical of the presented image restoration.

in audio, there are papers like [this](https://www.lncc.br/%7Epesquef/publications/other/Technical_rep72.pdf) and [this](http://audio.rightmark.org/lukin/pub/LukinTodd10.pdf).  i am sure there are more.  i just stumbled upon them by googling "[AES interpolating gaps in audio data](https://www.google.com/search?q=AES+interpolating+gaps+in+audio+data&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS743US743&oq=AES+interpolating+gaps+in+audio+data&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.19820j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)".